# Concatenate strings used for material UI card properties

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'd really like this to work, but it doesn't. It bleats about '> expected'.

```
 <CardHeader
     titleTypographyProps={{ variant: 'h4' }}
     title="Account Details"
     subheader="account number: " + {props.account.number}
 />
```

How do i get the subheader to show as 'account number: 123'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
    <CardHeader
        titleTypographyProps={{ variant: 'h4' }}
        title="Account Details"
        subheader= {"account number: " + props.account.number}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use it like :

```
subheader={`accountNumber:${props.account.number}` }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do either this:

```
<CardHeader
     titleTypographyProps={{ variant: 'h4' }}
     title="Account Details"
     subheader={"account number: " + {props.account.number}}
 />
```

or using template literal

```
<CardHeader
     titleTypographyProps={{ variant: 'h4' }}
     title="Account Details"
     subheader={`account number: ${props.account.number}`}
 />
```